# Where to download official Wiko Jerry drivers for ADB/USB connection?

Tags: adb, usb-drivers

I'm failing to find the page with original drivers, I only find third party websites that I don't know if I can trust. The manufacturer website is lacking the drivers (apparently). I'm using Windows 10 and have already the Whole NDK installed.

Comment: Download any MTK drivers. Wiko devices are powered by Mediatek chips.

Comment: Weren't Android supposed to have a unified driver for all devices? Or was I just dreaming? XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[wikogeek](http://wikogeek.com/) is a site dedicated to Wiko phones and hence presumably safe. Site description says

> ...the site dedicated for open source of Wiko products. We are pleased to provide the source codes of our mobile phones to our most sophisticated users....

It is likely to be safe since this site was referenced in [Wiko Forums](http://wikoandco.com/search/usb+drivers) . That's in French and needs translation and also explains the procedure of installing drivers

Comment: I speak French, can I help?

Comment: @esQmo: thanks +1 for your answer. If you can read that page and anything useful to the answer, please leave it in comments here

Answer (score 5):

You just need Mediatek drivers for any phone powered by an MTK chip. Since [all] Wiko devices are powered by Mediatek chips, you can use drivers for Alcatel MTK, or ZTE, etc. 
Go [here](http://firmwarefile.com/wiko-jerry) to download the firmware which contains the flashtool, drivers and instructions.

or [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-wiko-usb-drivers) to get the Wiko drivers (VCOM and CDC)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all answers, I also found an alternative way

Basically the drivers are on the phone, just need to browse it and install from there:

- the **official documentation** regarding that is:

[Install Wiko Jerry drivers](http://it.wikomobile.com/documents/GLOBAL/pdf/Window10.pdf)

- As Always you need to **enable developer mode**, **usb debugging** and when the phone prompt for it, allow your connected PC to be used for USB debugging.